# Questions with non-score answers are hard to identify

Tags: feature-request

Have a look at that screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Now while you can easily identify questions with no answers and questions with accepted answers, it is quite hard to do so for non-score answers (red mark). The [question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/7560/iodate-ion-io3-is-it-polar-or-non-polar) has two answers, but neither of them has an upvote (yet). The questions [above](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/7406/why-is-lanthanum-a-lanthanide-and-actinium-an-actinide) and [below](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/10184/how-does-the-process-of-protein-denaturatation-work) have voted answers, yet they look the same.

Since the community here is very small and a lot of people are asking questions and then not accepting answers (checking the mark), we have unfortunately rely on the upvoting system. I sometimes do not have much time to read all the questions and all the answers, so I would rather focus on answers that have no upvote. Then either improving existing answers by comment, or simply upvoting if it is good as it is. (As a last resort, write a new answer.) This might overall help the unanswered question problem.

I would like to be able to identify these questions on the go. Now to the actual question:
**Is it possible to have the colour in the summary for described scenario changed from green to black?**

---

**EDIT**

I wonder if this question is more in the scope of [meta.se](https://meta.stackexchange.com/)? What do you think? Should there be more or less elaboration?

Comment: Since this change would affect all beta sites (since they are all styled the same), it would certainly be appropriate for [meta.SE].